# Jetpack Compose. Есть ли буфер у LazyColumn?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

LazyColumn долго подгружает последний item из-за того, что в нем видео. Если способ увеличить буфер в LazyColumn?
Использование Column не подходит.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.